# ASP.NET MVC 1 or MVC 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I recently recieved the [*ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Professional*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) book by Wrox, and in the intervening time, I found out that ASP.NET MVC 2.0 is being released soon.

#### Questions

1. Should I MVC 2.0? Are there any resources specifically for MVC 2.0?
2. Should I learn MVC 1 and then unlearn concepts and then learn MVC 2?

Comment: thanks for the edit.I never added that book name, Is that for an advertisement?

Comment: Note that MVC 3 is now available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference between MVC 1 and MVC 2 are not like the difference between classic ASP and ASP.NET. What I mean is that if you learn MVC 1 you will be able to use everything in MVC 2. MVC 2 for the most part builds on top of MVC 1. So if you have an MVC 1 book I'd say read it and then read articles on what is new in MVC 2. Besides some [blogs](http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=ASP.NET+MVC+2) and articles I don't think there is much else on MVC 2 right now.

Answer (score 2):

MVC 2 is still in Beta (at least the last time I checked).

MVC 1 and MVC 2 use similar concepts...MVC 2 just adds features. Learn MVC 1 as a stepping stone, and then you can better utilize the new advanced features being released in MVC 2.

Comment: It is now RC, functionality wise it should not change.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I recommend that you learn and focus on MVC 1, but also read some of the upcoming changes in MVC 2. This way, as you're working on your MVC 1 project, you can see how MVC 2 features could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely released yet but people are using it. Actually, you are fine to use MVC version 1 resources to learn it and read up on what's new. A lot of what's there is just to make things a little easier, like the new syntax changes for HTML encoding etc.