# Difference between Asp.net MVC 1 and Asp.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What is difference between Asp.net MVC 1 and Asp.net MVC 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000446/asp-net-mvc-1-or-mvc-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These pages will tell you everything:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/presentations/whats-new-in-asp.net-mvc-2.pdf

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx

http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT04

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc/ 'recommended.